# Getting all mails from a shared folder in Outlook using Graph API

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail, outlook-graph-api

I am trying to get all mails from a shared folder in the following location (Folder2):
\Public folders - me@domain.com\All public folders\Folder1\Folder2

I want to do this using Blue Prism as I am a RPA developer. This means that I am going to use a HTTP request.

I have tried following URLs without much luck:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user id}/messages/

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user id}/mailfolders('Inbox')/messages

Does anyone know if I am using the wrong URL, what exactly goes in place of {user id} and 'Inbox' or if it is something else completely?

Comment: I'm presuming these are Outlook folders?

Comment: I'll leave it for now, but ultimately this question doesn't benefit materially from being tagged [tag:blueprism], as the answers to the question as it currently stands ultimately won't vary depending on which tool will be used to consume the API.

Comment: Yes this is correct, Zac.

Comment: Can you share how do you resolve this issue (i used a powershell script to perform something like that)